# Fourier transform of a real function is real

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I was trying to find the Fourier transform of the function

$$x \mapsto \frac1{x^2 - 2x  +2}$$

and I keep getting something with non-zero imaginary part. But the Fourier transform of a real function should be real, right? So I must be making a mistake?

What is a proof that the Fourier transform of a real function is real?

Comment: It ain't true.  Realness of $f$ corresponds to a certain type of symmetry in $\hat{f}$, which is not the same as realness.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Basic_properties

Comment: The Fourier transform of an even real function is real.  Maybe that's what you're thinking of.  Your function is not even (if you call it $f$, $x \mapsto f(x-1)$ is even).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following are equivalent:

1. $f(-x)=\overline{f(x)}$ for a.e. $x\in\mathbb R$
2. $\hat f(\xi)\in\mathbb R$ for a.e. $x\in\mathbb R$

The proof is immediate from 
$$
\overline{\hat f(\xi)} = \int_{\mathbb R} \overline{f(x)}e^{2\pi i x \xi}\,dx 
 = \int_{\mathbb R} \overline{f(-x)}e^{-2\pi i x \xi}\,dx
$$

Answer (score 0):

The definition of Fourier transform is that famous formula and will not necessarily produce real coefficients for a real function. But we should know that if the Fourier transform exists for a real function, we can also write that function with only real trigonometric functions.

if $f(x)$ is real then $f(x) = f^*(x)$ (which is its conjugate). Then we can prove that $F(\omega) = F^*(-\omega)$:

$$
f(x) = \int_{\mathbb R} F(\omega)e^{i\omega x}\,d_\omega 
\\
= f^*(x) = \int_{\mathbb R} [F(\omega)e^{i\omega x}]^*\,d_\omega = \int_{\mathbb R} F^*(\omega)e^{-i\omega x}\,d_\omega 
\\
\overset{\overline{\omega} = -\omega}{=} \int_{\mathbb R} F^*(-\overline{\omega})e^{i\overline{\omega} x}\,d_{\overline{\omega}} 
\\
\Rightarrow  F(\omega) = F^*(-\omega)
$$

Now we can simplify it:

$$f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{0} F(\omega)e^{i\omega x}\,d_\omega + \int_{0}^{+\infty} F(\omega)e^{i\omega x}\,d_\omega  
\\
= \int_{0}^{+\infty} F(-\omega)e^{-i\omega x}\,d_\omega + \int_{0}^{+\infty} F(\omega)e^{i\omega x}\,d_\omega
\\
 = \int_{0}^{+\infty} [F^*(\omega)e^{-i\omega x} + F(\omega)e^{i\omega x}]\,d_\omega 
\\
= 2\int_{0}^{+\infty} Real\{F(\omega)e^{i\omega x}\}\,d_\omega$$

Now, we can simplify $2\int_{0}^{+\infty} Real\{F(\omega)e^{i\omega x}\}\,d_\omega$ even more by assuming $F(\omega) = R_{\omega} + iJ_{\omega}$ (which R and J are the real and imaginary values).

$$
2\int_{0}^{+\infty} Real\{F(\omega)e^{i\omega x}\}\,d_\omega = 2\int_{0}^{+\infty} [R_{\omega}\cos{\omega x} - J_{\omega}\sin{\omega x}]\,d_\omega
\\
= 2\int_{0}^{+\infty} F_{l}(\omega)\sin[{\omega x + F_{\phi}(\omega)}] \,d_\omega
$$
Where $F_{l} = \sqrt{R^2_{\omega} + J^2_{\omega}}$ and $F_{\phi} = \arctan{-\frac{R_{\omega}}{J_{\omega}}}$.

Please notice that even in this case, we need two functions, $F_{l}$ and $F_{\phi}$, but everything is in real domain.